Como inhabilitar arranque por defecto de Apache2 y MariaDB en distribucion linux que usa sysVinit en logar de systemd
Me cambie de Linux debian 11 a Loc OS basado en debian 12. Quiero crear mi pagina personal con para mostrar mi futuro portafolio con Wordpress he instale Apache2, MariaDB y PHP.
En Debian yo podia desabilitar el arranque por defecto de Apache2 y MariaDB con:
sudo systemctl disable apache2 mysql 
o
sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable
sudo update-rc.d mysql disable

El problema es que ninguna de esas configuraciones no me funcionan con un Linux que utiliza sysVinit
Ya se como parar y arrancar Apache2 y MariaDB con los comandos
Apache:
sudo apachectl stop
sudo apachectl start

MariaDB:
sudo /etc/init.d/mariadb stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mariadb star

Lo que no se es como deshabilitar el arranque por defecto de ambos y quiero hacerlo ya que relentizan un poco la maquina y se que con el tiempo tardara mas y mas el arranque. Gracias y disculpen la molestia.

Te recomiendo googlear "sys v init linux disable"

Ya sé cómo inhabilitar Apache2 y MariaDB para que no arranquen por defecto al arrancar Linux con sysVinit con los comandos "sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable" y "sudo update-rc.d mariadb disable" Muchas gracias

Hola Marco, si conseguiste solucionarlo, crea una respuesta a tu propia pregunta y dentro de 48hs va a poder marcarla como aceptada. Saludos!
